# What is the live session user password in Kubuntu 15.04?

Tags: password, livedvd

What is the live session user password in Kubuntu 15.04? Furthermore, why is there a password for the live user at all?

Comment: There is no password.

Answer (score 1):

try username: ubuntu and leave the password blank. Also other problem with it is also that running programs are gone when you log in again.